# 405 Method not allowed on Net::HTTP request [ruby on rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers

I'm trying to verify if there is a remote url with following code:

```
endpoint_uri = URI.parse(@endpoint.url)
endpoint_http = Net::HTTP.new(endpoint_uri.host, endpoint_uri.port)
endpoint_request = Net::HTTP::Head.new(endpoint_uri.request_uri)
endpoint_response = endpoint_http.request(endpoint_request)
```

I'm still getting 405 Method not allowed. When I use `Get` instead `Head` in `Net::HTTP::Head.new` I'm getting 200 Success but also with whole remote document in response what results in bigger response time (0.3s => 0.9s).

Any ideas why this is happening? Thx

Answer (score 5):

There's a chance that the `@endpoint` url you're trying to interact with doesn't support HEAD requests (which would be really weird, but still may be the case). Your code works fine for me with a handful of urls (google.com, stackoverflow.com, etc.)

Have you tried a curl request to see what it returns?

```
curl -I http://www.the_website_you_want_to_test.com
```

Comment: it's weird like you said but see what it returns `curl -I http://www.kirupafx.com/WebService/TopMovies.asmx?WSDL` **405 Method not allowed**. Anyway thanks for command `curl` and answer