# Request headers only using Ruby HTTPClient returns 405 http status code (Method not allowed) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, google-drive-api, http-status-code-405

My Ruby on Rails application (ruby 2.6.6; rails 5.2) makes a header only request using HTTPClient, for a Google Drive direct download link. This is to check if the file is really there.

The code is:

```
response = client.head(<google_drive_direct_download_url>, follow_redirect: true)
```

This results in 405 status code.

But, at the same time, I can make a normal request to the same URL using

```
response = client.request('GET', <google_drive_direct_download_url>, follow_redirect: true)
```

obtaining status code 200.

There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904208/405-method-not-allowed-on-nethttp-request-ruby-on-rails) saying there is a chance that the URL endpoint doesn't accept header only requests.

But I do can make a header only request using `httpie` receinving 200:

```
$ http <google_drive_direct_download_url> -h --follow
```

Would be a matter of outdated version, or there's an issue with HTTPClient?

Comment: With `http -h ...` you are still making a full `GET` request, the client is just throwing away the response body. As such, it's still likely that Google Drive just doesn't support HEAD requests.

Comment: Are you sure @HolgerJust? I tested with a GET for a large file and the response time when using `-h` is a fraction of second, while making without it it took more time to effectively download the file.